# Erro para pegar o último ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá. Estou tendo problemas para pegar o último ID cadastrado. Já fiz um monte de tentativas, mas a variável $proximo_ID sempre me retorna '0', ou Vazio. Vocês poderiam me ajudar a solucionar o problema?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn-cadastro'])) {

try {

    $wID = $_REQUEST['cadastro_ID'];

    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);

    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT ID FROM tbl_casualidade WHERE ID = :wID');
    $stmt->execute(array('wID' => $wID));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (count($result)){ 

foreach($result as $row){

    $proximo_ID = $DB_con->lastInsertId();

        }
    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $modelo = '<div id="link_'.$proximo_ID.'"></div>';

try {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_casualidade (ID, nome, modelo) VALUES ('$ID', '".$nome."', '".$modelo."')";

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' style='margin-top: 57px; margin-left: 45px; margin-bottom: -60px; margin-right: 15px;'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
            <strong>PERFEITO!</strong> Página cadastrada com sucesso...
        </div>";
    }

catch(PDOException $e)

    {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' style='margin-top: 57px; margin-left: 45px; margin-bottom: -60px; margin-right: 15px;'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
                <strong>FALHA!</strong> Por favor, tente enviar novamente...
            </div><br />";

    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$DB_con = null;
```

}

Comment: Você está tentando pegar o último id antes de inserir?
Não há necessidade de 2 try {} sendo que você está fazendo apenas uma operação no bd.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Eu preciso antes de inserir ver qual foi o ultimo ID e passa-lo para a variável $proximoID

Comment: Então use apenas `select max(id) + 1 as id from tbl_casualidade`
Se você não inseriu, não há como pegar o último id inserido.

Comment: Mas não tem como antes de eu inserir, eu verificar qual é o ultimo id que esta cadastrado no banco e acrescentar +1?

Comment: Já postei: `select max(id) + 1 as id from tbl_casualidade`

Troque o treco foreach{} inteiro por `$proximo_ID = $result[0]['id']`

Comment: Fiz exatamente como vc comentou, mas o valor vem vazio.

Comment: Se for o primeiro registro retorna vazio mesmo!
Corrigindo: `select ifnull(max(id),0) + 1 as id from tbl_casualidade`

Comment: Agora não vem vazio, mas vem sempre 1.

Comment: O Campo id não é auto_increment | identity ?
Outra questão: de onde vem o $ID em `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_casualidade (ID, nome, modelo) VALUES ('$ID', '".$nome."', '".$modelo."')";`

Se for auto_increment substitua por `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_casualidade (nome, modelo) VALUES ({$nome}, {$modelo})";`

Comment: Deu certo. Eu estava passando o parâmetro do $_REQUEST com nome errado. Muito Obrigado Maurivan.

Comment: Aiello, por nada! Disponha.

Comment: Se quer acrescentar mais um, faça `$variavel++` com o resultado recebido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem dessa forma:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT IFNULL (max(`ID`),0) FROM tbl_casualidade');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$ct=$result[0];
```

Ou dessa:

```
$control=mysqli_query($conn,"select ifnull(max(ID),0)from tbl_casualidade");
$controll=mysqli_fetch_row($control);

$ct=$controll[0];
```

Particularmente uso essa ultima. Esse comando SELECT selecionar e analisa todos os registros, devolvendo o maior encontrado  na posição [0].

Comment: Olá Danilo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se ajudou aceite a resposta e pontue.Obrigado